# Formatting Dates with non-standard format

Tags: r, date, formatting, timestamp

I'm relatively new to this site so forgive me if my question is a bit vague for you guys. I also realize there are many threads on this topic, yet I feel they do not answer my question specifically since they are almost all about changing yy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yy or vice versa.

In short what do i want? I want my current format changed into only year.

I have a column full of dates of this format.

```
31OCT2016:23:52:00.000
```

I've seen in many topics you can use format commands but they go something like this;

```
dates <- c("05/27/84", "07/07/05")
```

I have over 100.000 observations so this can't be done manually.
So I tried;

```
mydata$dates <- format(as.Date(mydata$dates), "%Y")
```

But that didn't work. I saw on this website the proper values

http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

But it did not say anything on how to get rid of hours minutes and seconds.

So what is the easiest way to strip it all down to year only?

Comment: oh sorry its in R

Answer (score 1):

`Lubridate` is your friend. To be precise, the function `dmy_hms`:

I'll generate some sample data which has the same format as your example so my code is reproducible. Don't worry about it too much. For your purposes, you can jump right to the conversion part.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#This code block is entirely for generating reproducible sample data

d <- sample(1:27,10,T)
mon <- toupper(sample(month.abb,10,T))
y <- sample(2000:2017,10,T)
h <- sample(0:23,10,T)
min <- sample(0:59,10,T)
s <- sample(0:59,10,T)

#load package
library(lubridate)

dts <- sprintf('%02d%s%s:%s:%s:%s.000',d,mon,y,h,min,s)

> dts
 [1] "01JAN2012:12:6:53.000"  "01NOV2010:0:19:47.000"  "03SEP2000:9:45:3.000"   "25NOV2009:21:39:57.000" "08DEC2015:19:27:36.000"
 [6] "23MAR2009:13:39:40.000" "03JUN2010:14:54:50.000" "03APR2002:6:34:45.000"  "19NOV2012:5:17:29.000"  "02FEB2003:0:3:59.000" 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So basically the variable `dts` is your column full of dates which you want to convert:

```
#conversion

> dmy_hms(dts)
 [1] "2012-01-01 12:06:53 UTC" "2010-11-01 00:19:47 UTC" "2000-09-03 09:45:03 UTC" "2009-11-25 21:39:57 UTC"
 [5] "2015-12-08 19:27:36 UTC" "2009-03-23 13:39:40 UTC" "2010-06-03 14:54:50 UTC" "2002-04-03 06:34:45 UTC"
 [9] "2012-11-19 05:17:29 UTC" "2003-02-02 00:03:59 UTC"
```

And then to get just the years, you can use the `year` function:

```
> year(dmy_hms(dts))
 [1] 2012 2010 2000 2009 2015 2009 2010 2002 2012 2003
```

---

So assuming you want to do everything inside the `data.frame`, your code could look like this:

```
# example dataframe
dframe <- data.frame(variable=c('A','B','C'),dates=sample(dts,3))
```

This is a data frame with some variable and the column with the dates.

```
> dframe
  variable                 dates
1        A  15JAN2000:0:37:6.000
2        B 13DEC2016:8:34:28.000
3        C 18AUG2005:2:27:16.000
```

So to convert the dates, we can simply do `dframe$dates <- year(dmy_hms(dframe$dates))`

If we look at `dframe` again, we can see that the conversion was successful:

```
> dframe
  variable dates
1        A  2000
2        B  2016
3        C  2005
```

Comment: I’m fairly new to it. The generate data part I do not fully understand. Shouldn’t I load in my own data there? What is it that you do there exactly? 

part 2, If I understand correct this is my current format that needs to be defined in order to get formatted later in part 3. 

    'dts <- sprintf('%02d%s%s:%s:%s:%s.000',d,mon,y,h,min,s)'

Then you show how dts looks with command
   > dts

Then in part 3 you show how conversion is done by
   ' > dmy_hms(dts)'

And display the result. Then a follow up question from here is, how do I get that result into a new column in my dataset?

Comment: @Val one addition: if default time locale isn't 'English' you should specify it explicitly: `dmy_hms(dts, locale = "English")`.
@Thundersheep if you that new, it's probably good idea to read on basic R operations with data.frames. Basicly what you need to do is: `df$year <-  year(dmy_hms(df$date))` where `df` is the name of your data.frame and `date` in `df$date` is name of your dates column.

Comment: Hmm interesting @AndreyKolyadin I did what you both said and it 72.000/300.000 failed but the others seem to have worked. At the moment im trying to find out why some worked and others not.

Comment: @Thundersheep hopefully my edits will make it a bit clearer. @AndreyKolyadin if you use "English", you'll get a warning returned that the locale can't be honored. I guess you can set the locale with `locale = "en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: could it be because of this? Should i tweak these numbers?

d <- sample(1:27,10,T)
mon <- toupper(sample(month.abb,10,T))
y <- sample(2000:2017,10,T)
h <- sample(0:23,10,T)
min <- sample(0:59,10,T)
s <- sample(0:59,10,T)

Comment: @Thundersheep Don't use the data I produced .. try with your dates in `mydata$dates`

Comment: Thanks I will, however when i run;

 mydata$dates <- sprintf('%02d%s%s:%s:%s:%s.000',d,mon,y,h,min,s)
Error in sprintf("%d%s%s:%s:%s:%s.000", d, mon, y, h, min, s) : 
  object 'd' not found

Comment: `sprintf` is only for generating the sample data ... it's not necessary to convert the dates. If you choose to create my sample data, you need to execute all the lines above (including the one which generates the variable `d`). But again, this is not part of the conversion

Comment: I think i get it now, however only 70.000 of the 300.000 observations that i have work. 

library(lubridate)
dmy_hms(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR)
year(dmy_hms(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR))
mydata$year <- year(dmy_hms(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR))

this is what i run and with that i generate also a new column. Most dates are conversed and I have a neat column with years. Just also 70.000 NA'S.... Still don't know how that could happen

Comment: [1] 2012 2015 2015 2015 2013 2015 2015 2013   NA 2008 2008   NA   NA 2007 2013   NA 2016 2014 2014   NA 2014 2015   NA

Comment: This `mydata$year <- year(dmy_hms(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR))` would be the only line you need to run. If you're getting `NA`s, the format of the initial date was probably different from your example.

Comment: Look at the output of `mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR[is.na(mydata$year)]` and see if the format differs

Comment: Indeed I noticed one line is sufficient. thanks for the help so far. I was thinking the same thing, must be the input of the dates. But have a look at this.. looks completely random to me. http://i174.photobucket.com/albums/w85/thundersheep/screenshot_zpslbkbu7sy.png

Comment: Interesting. It's hard to say why this happens. You could try setting the locale to english: `mydata$year <- year(dmy_hms(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR,locale="en_US.UTF-8"))`

Comment: hmm does not seem to work

Warning messages:
1: In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale) :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
2:  79071 failed to parse.

Comment: Try `year(dmy(regmatches(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR,regexpr('\\d{2}\\w{3}\\d{4}',mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR)))` ... this will essentially only use the day,month and year for the conversion and get rid of all the other stuff.

Comment: Worst case you can also just extract the year from the date instead of converting it: `mydata$year <- regmatches(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR,rege‌​xpr('\\d‌​{4}',mydata$obj_hid_‌​DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR‌​))`. This is more like a quick and dirty fix and rather unsatisfying. It would be better to investigate why some dates are not working. But this is not possible from my position.

Comment: Luck is not on our side today.
when i run your first command;

I get  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 282703 entries ]
Warning message:
 79071 failed to parse.

Comment: Strange. You can run only `regmatches(mydata$obj_hid_DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR,rege‌​xpr('\\d{2}\\w{3}\\d‌​{4}',mydata$obj_hid_‌​DATUM_LAATSTVRKOOPPR‌​))` and see if the format is homogeneous. It should be always DDMMMYYYY (e.g. 01OCT2015)

Comment: And you second command I get;
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, year, value = c("2012", "2015", "2015",  : 
  replacement has 283703 rows, data has 330072

But that is because I indeed have around 40.000 entries where that date isn't specified. (not 70k though, so still wondering why those who are entered not work)

However if I run the second command on my dates that has no missing values it works! But you said you didn't prefer this method.

Comment: yes it's homogeneous for those numbers that are printed.Since [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 282703 entries ]

Comment: It's not optimal, but if it works it's fine for now. You should pick out a date where the conversion doesn't work and figure out why not

Comment: Yeah it does, for now. At least i can make sub sets based on year now. Thank you very much for all your help so far. It does work for now.